# Truncation of distance matrix

Tags: sample, distance, truncation

Given a sample $\textbf{X}_1$,...,$\textbf{X}_n\in\mathbb{R}^p$ from an arbitrary distribution with distribution function $F$ we can calculate the pairwise Mahalanobis distances between the sample points as $$d_{ij} = (\textbf{X}_i - \textbf{X}_j)^T\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\textbf{X}_i - \textbf{X}_j).$$

Now suppose that the underlying distribution is standard multivariate Gaussian, in this case the distance will have a scaled $\chi^2_p$ distribution and we could truncate the distances by e.g.: the $0.05$ quantile of the $\chi^2_p$ distribution and have a data "data independent" and fast way of truncation.

What techniques do we have in case of an arbitrary distribution?
I was thinking about estimating the distribution function $F$ from the sample and using the same quantile approach, but is there an another way to do it?

Comment: Could you explain what this truncation is intended to accomplish?

Comment: I get a threshold by calculating the quantile $q$ and truncate the elements of the matrix by modifying the "too large" elements as $d_{ij} = \infty$, if $d_{ij}>q$, but any other element would not change.
This way I would get a much sparser distance matrix.

Comment: In what sense would introducing a constant value in just 5% of the entries of the matrix make it "much" sparser?

Comment: You keep the 5%...

Comment: I see--you're retaining only values nearest the center of the distribution.  That would seem to throw away most of the information in the data, though.  Indeed, in many circumstances you would have *more* information by retaining only the components of $\Sigma^{-1}.$ One situation where this would not be true is where you are using $(d_{ij})$ to find nearest neighbors: is that the application?

Comment: Yes, we would like to find nearest neighbors therefore we want to retain values near distance 0, although the center of the distribution is not 0.